# python playwright as a class variable - weird behaviour

Tags: playwright-python

I used before some code for web scraping like task with selenium, and it worked as expected.

Now I tried to rewrite this code with playwright and encountered weird behavior.

Below is the sample of the code.
But on console output, I can see something like this:

```
init - start
log_in - start
get_rid_of_pop_up_window - start
init - end
mark 1
mark 2
```

Any suggestion how to do that right?

```python
from playwright.sync_api import Playwright, sync_playwright

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, playwright: Playwright):
        print('init - start')
        self.browser = playwright.firefox.launch(headless=False)
        self.context = self.browser.new_context()
        self.page = self.context.new_page()
        self.page.goto("https://example.com/")

        self.my_name = 'my'
        self.my_pass = '123'

        print('init - end')

    def get_rid_of_pop_up_window(self):
        print('get_rid_of_pop_up_window - start')
        self.page.frame_locator("iframe[title=\"SP Consent Message\"]").get_by_role("button", name="Settings").click()
        self.page.frame_locator("#sp_message_iframe_123").get_by_role("button", name="Save").click()
        print('get_rid_of_pop_up_window - end')

    def log_in(self):
        print('log_in - start')
        self.get_rid_of_pop_up_window()
        self.page.locator("form").filter(has_text="sign-in") \
            .get_by_placeholder("user").fill(self.my_name)
        print('mark 1')
        self.page.locator("form").filter(has_text="sign-in") \
            .get_by_placeholder("pass").fill(self.my_pass)
        print('mark 2')
        self.page.locator("form").filter(has_text="sign-in") \
            .get_by_role("button", name="go").click()
        print('log_in - end')

with sync_playwright() as pw:
    my_object = MyClass(pw)
    my_object.log_in()
```

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you are experiencing should be linked to the synchronous nature of the [`sync_playwright` library](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-playwright): when you call `my_object.log_in()`, it triggers the execution of the `log_in` method, which in turn calls `get_rid_of_pop_up_window`. However, `get_rid_of_pop_up_window` performs some asynchronous actions that do not block the execution of the script.

In the case of Playwright, most actions are asynchronous and non-blocking by default. When you call `self.page.frame_locator("iframe[title=\"SP Consent Message\"]").get_by_role("button", name="Settings").click()`, it starts an asynchronous action, but does not wait for it to complete before moving on to the next line of code.

To fix this, you need to make the code wait for asynchronous actions to complete. You can use the [`wait_for_timeout` method](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-timeout) to introduce a delay, or the `wait_for_selector` method to wait for a specific selector to appear before proceeding.
However, that method is "discouraged":

> Never wait for timeout in production. Tests that wait for time are inherently flaky. Use [`Locator`](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-locator) actions and web assertions that wait automatically.

In the Playwright library, locators are the recommended way to interact with elements on the page. They automatically wait for the element to be available and visible, which can help make your code more reliable.

Here is how your code might look using locators:

```py
from playwright.sync_api import Playwright, sync_playwright

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, playwright: Playwright):
        print('init - start')
        self.browser = playwright.firefox.launch(headless=False)
        self.context = self.browser.new_context()
        self.page = self.context.new_page()
        self.page.goto("https://example.com/")
        self.page.wait_for_url("https://example.com/")  # Add this line

        self.my_name = 'my'
        self.my_pass = '123'

        print('init - end')


    def get_rid_of_pop_up_window(self):
        print('get_rid_of_pop_up_window - start')
        self.page.frame_locator("iframe[title=\"SP Consent Message\"]").get_by_role("button", name="Settings").click()
        self.page.frame_locator("#sp_message_iframe_123").get_by_role("button", name="Save").click()
        print('get_rid_of_pop_up_window - end')

    def log_in(self):
        print('log_in - start')
        self.get_rid_of_pop_up_window()

        username_locator = self.page.locator("form").filter(has_text="sign-in").get_by_placeholder("user")
        username_locator.wait_for()
        username_locator.fill(self.my_name)
        print('mark 1')

        password_locator = self.page.locator("form").filter(has_text="sign-in").get_by_placeholder("pass")
        password_locator.wait_for()
        password_locator.fill(self.my_pass)
        print('mark 2')

        login_button_locator = self.page.locator("form").filter(has_text="sign-in").get_by_role("button", name="go")
        login_button_locator.wait_for()
        login_button_locator.click()

        # Wait for the page to navigate after login
        self.page.wait_for_url("**/target.html")  # Replace with the actual URL you expect after login
        print('log_in - end')

with sync_playwright() as pw:
    my_object = MyClass(pw)
    my_object.log_in()
```

I have used `locator.wait_for()` instead of `page.wait_for_selector` calls. This waits for the locator to be visible before proceeding, which should help ensure the correct sequence of operations. I have also created a `form_locator` variable to avoid duplicating the "`form:has-text('sign-in')`" locator in multiple places.

By using `Locator` actions and waiting for specific selectors, we avoid the need for explicit timeouts and rely on the built-in waiting behavior of Playwright, resulting in more reliable and less flaky code.

By properly waiting for elements to appear, you ensure that the actions are performed at the correct time, avoiding the unexpected behavior you encountered.

The `page.waitForURL("**/target.html")` line waits for the page to navigate to the specified URL after the login action is performed. You will need to replace `"**/target.html"` with the actual URL you expect to navigate to after login.

Please note that Playwright's glob pattern `**` matches any sequence of characters, including `/`, and `*` matches any sequence of characters excluding `/`. So `"**/target.html"` matches URLs ending with `/target.html`.

---

The main issue remains that the output order of the print statements does not match the expected sequence of function calls. This is unusual, because the `__init__` function should complete fully (including printing `init - end`) before the `log_in` function starts.

When you are launching the browser, creating a new context, opening a new page, and navigating to a URL in the `__init__` function, these actions might not be completing before the `log_in` function starts.

To address this, I would try, for testing, to use Playwright's auto-waiting mechanism more explicitly and ensure that each action completes before the next one starts. This might involve using the `wait_for_url` method after the `goto` method in the `__init__` function to ensure that the page finishes navigating before proceeding.

---

Another approach, to ensure that the `__init__` method completes before the `log_in` method begins, is to use a separate method to initialize the Playwright actions and then call this method before calling the `log_in` method.

That would be:

```py
from playwright.sync_api import Playwright, sync_playwright

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, playwright: Playwright):
        print('init - start')
        self.browser = playwright.firefox.launch(headless=False)
        self.context = self.browser.new_context()
        self.page = self.context.new_page()

        self.my_name = 'my'
        self.my_pass = '123'
        print('init - end')

    def go_to_page(self):
        self.page.goto("https://example.com/")
        self.page.wait_for_url("https://example.com/**")  # Add this line

    def get_rid_of_pop_up_window(self):
        print('get_rid_of_pop_up_window - start')
        self.page.frame_locator("iframe[title=\"SP Consent Message\"]").get_by_role("button", name="Settings").click()
        self.page.frame_locator("#sp_message_iframe_123").get_by_role("button", name="Save").click()
        print('get_rid_of_pop_up_window - end')

    def log_in(self):
        print('log_in - start')
        self.get_rid_of_pop_up_window()
        
        self.page.locator("form").filter(has_text="sign-in").get_by_placeholder("user").fill(self.my_name)
        print('mark 1')
        self.page.locator("form").filter(has_text="sign-in").get_by_placeholder("pass").fill(self.my_pass)
        print('mark 2')
        self.page.locator("form").filter(has_text="sign-in").get_by_role("button", name="go").click()

        # Wait for the page to navigate after login
        self.page.wait_for_url("**/target.html")  # Replace with the actual URL you expect after login
        print('log_in - end')

with sync_playwright() as pw:
    my_object = MyClass(pw)
    my_object.go_to_page()
    my_object.log_in()
```

In this updated code, the `go_to_page` method navigates to the URL and waits for the navigation to complete. The `go_to_page` method is called before the `log_in` method, so it should ensure that the `init - end` message appears before the `log_in - start` message.

Comment: I forgot to type `self.page.goto("https://example.com/")`. Now I updated it. Apologize for that. @VonC thank you for your effort and quite exhaustive explanation. However if I try your code `self.page.wait_for_selector("iframe[title=\"SP Consent Message\"]").click()` I received timeout exception, even I can clearly see that element is already present on the screen. Also when I hover over the 'filter' in code `form_locator.wait_for().filter(has_text="sign-in").get_by_placeholder("user").fill(self.my_name)` I can read python complian: Cannot find reference 'filter' in 'None'

Comment: @XORer OK, I have updated the answer to address your comment.

Comment: I tried your code, checked twice that I wrote it as you proposed and good news is that it works - I am logged in, but so I was with my original code, which was by the way generated with this playwright codegen feature. So I just copied and pasted it to my class. Bad news is that in output console I can still see the same mess as before.

Comment: @XORer OK. I tried and added a `self.page.wait_for_url("**/target.html") `

Comment: I realy appreciate that you are still willing to help, but if you look at very top - to that console output, it can be seen that there is no `__init__ - end`, before `log_in - start` and now you just added some code to the end of log_in method. Unfortunately I can not reproduce your proposal fully because when I log in the my actual url is composed from fixed start part + unique identifier on the end so I had to try `https://example.com/**` instead. But I understand that ** is some sort of regex, so probably it should work as well, but unfortunately in console output still the same mess.

Comment: @XORer OK, for testing, I have added one line in the __init__ function. See the last edit for more.

Comment: still no luck - I can not see `__init__ - end` before `log_in - start`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253957/discussion-between-vonc-and-xorer).